# Before my custom initializer can start, the superclass' throws an exception

Tags: java, constructor, initializer

I have my own class that extends an external class that overrides an external class to make its text always `"Hello"`. It looks like:

```java
import ext.ExternalClassA;

public class ClassB extends ExternalClassA {
    private String customText = "Hello";

    public ClassB() { // line 6
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String newText) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return customText;
    }
}
```

However, when I run my program, it crashes with an error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ext.ExternalClassA.setup(ExternalClassA.java:123)
    at ext.ExternalClassA.<init>(ExternalClassA.java:45)
    at my.ClassB.<init>(ClassB.java:6)
```

When I look at `ExternalClassA.java`, I see this:

```
// imports...

public class ExternalClassA {
    private String text;
    // Other variables

    public ClassB() {
        text = "Default";
        setup(); // line 45
    }

    // more code...

    private void setup() {
        if (text == null)
            return;
        String textStr = getText().toString(); // line 123

        // more code...
    }

    // more code...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it? Is it a problem with the external class?

Comment: I just ran into this when trying to override Swing methods. A couple searches on SO turned up no similar questions, but if you know of one, please link it in the comments so I can move my answer there.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors

Comment: Can you point us to the Swing class involved?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis `javax.swing.text.JTextComponent` (particularly setText(String), on line 1672 in Java 1.8.0_25)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `ExternalClassA` is attempting to use its `getText()` method to get text. As far as it sees, from the previous couple lines, this should be safe. However, unbeknownst to it, your override of `getText()` does not always return `text`. This may seem fine to you, since you use `customText`, which is set to `"Hello"`. **However!** This assignment does not happen until the superclass' initializer exits. Here is the order of initialization:

Only once:

1. superclass' static variables
2. superclass' static constructor
3. this' static variables
4. this' static constructor

Every new object:

5. superclass' variables
6. superclass' constructor
7. this' variables
8. this' constructor

So, when the superclass calls `getText()`, it goes into yours. In yours, at this moment, `customText` is `null`, but `superText` is `"Default"`.

This may seem like a no-win, since there's no way to set your value before the superclass is done initializing, **but there is a solution!** It lies within this same behavior. The same Java mechanic that defaults `customText` to `null` also defaults primitives to `0` or `false`. We can use this and modify `ClassB` like such:

```java
import ext.ExternalClassA;

public class ClassB extends ExternalClassA {
    private String customText = "Hello";
    private boolean hasStarted = true;

    public ClassB() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String newText) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        if (!hasStarted)
            return super.getText();
        return customText;
    }
}
```

Note that `hasStarted` will be `true` ONLY after the superclass' constructor has returned.

### tl;dr

---

> What am I doing wrong?

You didn't know that the order-of-operations in initialization causes your string to be `null` until your constructor has control.

> How can I fix it?

Fallback to superclass methods during super initialization.

> Is it a problem with the external class?

Yes, the superclass should not check a variable to assume the return value of a method.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `setup` next way:

```
public void setup() {
    setText("Hello");
    super.setup();
}
```

After  that you may drop all your stuff from ClassB.

Comment: On your last line, then what happens when someone calls `setText("a string")` on a `ClassB` object?